# Visa application for Egypt journey as a German citizen

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, egypt, german-citizens

I am a German citizen and will travel to Egypt for two weeks as a tourist.
A few questions regarding the visa application since the first google results seem pretty scammy (very much like for US ESTA...).

- I have a Passport, so I do not need to bring an additional biometric photograph which would be required if I travelled only with my national ID card. Is this correct?
- Is it advisable to apply for the visa online ahead of time? Does it save time and is there a way to do this without getting scammed?
- We arrive at Cairo airport very late in the evening. Can be apply there on arrival? What are the payment options fot that?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: after the very helpful answer by @phoog I did some research and found on https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/service/laender/aegypten-node/aegyptensicherheit/212622 that there exists an e-Visa for the same cost:
https://visa2egypt.gov.eg/eVisa/Home

Any experiences with this, does that work as described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the first google results seem pretty scammy": a better approach than using a search engine to find visa information is to use the search engine to find the destination country's consulate's or embassy's web page and then look for visa information on the page, possibly in a menu, and possibly under a heading such as "consular services."

Sure enough, at https://egyptian-embassy.de/ there is a prominent link for Visa-Informationen leading to a page with a visa information wizard, for which I chose these answers:

- visa type: tourist visa (single entry)
- Bundesland: Berlin
- nationality: Germany

This yielded the following:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,
>
> vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage. Für Staatsangehörige aus oben ausgewähltem Land gelten erleichterte Einreisebestimmungen, so dass Sie Ihr Visum bei der Einreise am Flughafen erhalten.
>
> Sie erhalten das Touristenvisum mit einmonatiger Gültigkeit bei der Einreise direkt an Ihrem Einreiseort in Ägypten mit einem Reisepass, der bei der Einreise noch mindestens 6 Monate gültig sein muss, sowie gegen eine Gebühr von 25 US-Dollar, bzw. Äquivalent in Euro (bar oder per Karte zu bezahlen)
>
> Staatsbürger von Deutschland, Italien, Frankreich, Belgien und Portugal können auch mit einem gültigen Personalausweis sowie zwei biometrischen Passbildern einreisen. Das Visum wird ebenfalls gegen die Gebühr von 25 US-Dollar, bzw. Äquivalent in Euro am Flughafen direkt ausgestellt.

Answer to your first question: yes, that is correct, you don't need the photographs if you have your passport.

Answer to your third question: yes, you can apply on arrival; it's not clear what the payment options are so you might want to bring some cash and include some small denominations in case they don't accept bank cards, use a precise exchange rate, and are unable to return change for overpayments.

> Alternativ dazu besteht auch die Möglichkeit, das Visum im Vorfeld schon in Deutschland zu beantragen. Eine Beantragung im Vorfeld kann nur mit einem gültigen Reisepass erfolgen, nicht mit dem Personalausweis. Die Bearbeitung des Antrags dauert ca. eine Woche. Das Visum kann frühestens drei Monate vor geplantem Reisebeginn beantragt werden.
>
> Für den Antrag wird benötigt (für jeden Antragsteller):
>
> - Reisepass im Original (mindestens sechs Monate gültig bei der geplanten Einreise)
> - Kopie der ersten Seite des Reisepasses
> - 2 Biometrische Passfotos
> - Kopie der Aufenthaltsgenehmigung (sofern vorhanden)
> - ausgefüllter Visaantrag (http://www.egyptian-embassy.de/images/visaform.pdf )
> - 22 Euro in bar (pro Antragsteller, für Deutsche), 38 Euro in bar (alle anderen Nationalitäten).
>
> Sie können das Visum persönlich während der Geschäftszeiten von Montag bis Freitag (außer an Feiertagen) von 9:30 bis 12:00 ohne vorherige Terminvergabe oder per Post beantragen.

Answer to your second question: no, it does not seem to be possible to apply for the visa online ahead of time.  To apply ahead of time you must apply by mail or in person.

> Bei der persönlichen Beantragung kann eine Ausstellung am selben Tag nicht garantiert werden. Bitte vereinbaren Sie daher bei der Abgabe einen Termin zur Abholung oder bringen sie einen einen adressierten und als Einschreiben frankierten Rückumschlag mit, mit dem der visierte Pass an Sie zurückgeschickt werden kann.
>
> Bitte achten Sie bei einer Beantragung auf dem Postweg darauf, den Antrag inklusive der Dokumente und der Gebühren in bar per Einschreiben zu verschicken, und den Einlieferungsbeleg aufzubewahren.
>
> Bitte legen Sie Ihrem Antrag einen adressierten und als Einschreiben frankierten Rückumschlag bei.
>
> Bitte wenden Sie sich für Ihren Antrag UNBEDINGT an das für Sie zuständige Konsulat
>
> Konsularbezirk Ost: Berlin, Brandenburg, Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Thüringen, Sachsen, Sachsen-Anhalt:
>
> Botschaft der Arabischen Republik Ägypten
>
> Konsularabteilung
> [Contact information omitted]

Obviously if you need a different type of visa or live in a different Bundesland then you'll want to redo the visa wizard yourself with the appropriate information.  For example, the longer-duration tourist visa is not available on arrival.

Comment: It is indeed [possible to apply for an Egyptian visa online](https://visa2egypt.gov.eg/), and [German citizens are among the eligible nationalities](https://visa2egypt.gov.eg/eVisa/FAQ).